# How to make my application look for resources starting on the application base and not the domain?

Tags: java, html

We have a Java web application that uses Spring MVC and Thymeleaf.
We have always used this application through some url like this: "company.myApp.com" and it behave well under this conditions.
We now have a potential customer that would like to have their own server with a url like this
www.customer.com/myApp

The problem that arrives from that is that any resource (image, JS, CSS and so on) that is referenced in using "/" at the beginning will not be found.
Example

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
```

Worked on our previous setup because the browser would look for it on comany.myApp.com/images/logo.png, where it is located.

If this same code is used in the second scenario, the image would not be found because the browser would look for it on www.customer.com/images/logo.png and the image it on www.customer.com/myApp/images/logo.png

Is there any way that I can use so the paths are always relative to the "application base" and no the domain?

I could have a settings entry that would be the application base and I could concatenate it when creating the view, but what could I do when setting image references on CSS, for instance?

ps: I know it sounds crazy, and I doubt that there is a way to do so because the browser has no idea how to know if /myApp is the application base or not, but this problem got me thinking that this scenario is not rare (an application that could be used in any path the user wants), so there may be a way to achieve it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152002/relative-paths-of-images-in-javascript

Comment: Kind of, this solves for javascript references, btu CSSs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that is kind of annoying to manage.  This is how I've always done it:

1) In your CSS that has references to image urls, use a relative path.  IE, if your images are in src/main/webapp/img and your css is in src/main/webapp/css, you can refer to an image in your css with url('../img/image.png')

2) What you're referring to as application path is called context path.  You can get this from the request.  So in order to grab an image (or other resource) based on your context path, you can do this:

```
<img src="${request.contextPath}/img/image.png" />
```